# Unable to extend Ubuntu with adjacent unused space after deleting windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I installed a dual boot Ubuntu after shrinking Windows, and it is working great for my classes right now, but I needed a virtual machine for seed labs with a specific image. I didn't have enough space to do this on the partition that I had made with Ubuntu. I had already backed up everything on Windows, I figured I could just remove windows and use all the space for Ubuntu. I used gparted after booting with the bootable disk I used to install Ubuntu and was able to delete windows, but when I try to move or extend Ubuntu, I can't. I've read that that is because it is mounted, but it's the only OS I have, so I don't know how to unmount it. [The space I want is adjacent to the 26 Gib Ubuntu I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cmKU.png)

I have preferences set on this OS that I like, so extending it would be ideal, but I wouldn't be too put out if I had to remove all OS and reinstall a new OS that occupies the unused space, I just don't have any option for that on start up, so I don't know how I would even go about that. Any advice would be great. Thank you.

[No options are available for extending or moving, just shrinking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdJg6.png)

Comment: To work on Linux partitions they have to be unmounted, best way is to boot from installer USB.  The easiest way for you to increase Ubuntu partition is to backup any data you want to keep and re install.  Can move partition to the right and extend, but good chance of this causing booting problems, that you will need to take time to fix.  Need to backup data before working on partitions or installing very important.  Lost of data possible.

Comment: I am on the installer usb -- i think --and I cannot unmount... should i try and create a new one?

Comment: Make sure, Ubuntu on hard drive should unmount if booted on USB.  Possible hard/ssd drive booted first if not careful, fast enough.  Can't unmount partition if loaded/booted/working.

Comment: I got my installation media to load after making a new one and using lenovo yoga's command Fn + F12 to boot with it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't actually booted with my bootable USB, I had to use Lenovo Yoga's command Fn + F12 to make the selection and the selection I wanted was not Ubuntu, Not Windows, but the 3rd option which was Linpus. I used a new bootable USB that I made for Ubuntu version 18 instead of the 20 I installed with, and this worked fine. I'm guessing the current version would have worked as well. It took me to a basically blank Ubuntu Desktop and I was able to open gparted and extend the partition.